# control the order of windows Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a way to control the order of other applications' windows through AIR application? All I could find in Adobe docs were `orderToFront()`, `orderInFrontOf()`, `orderToBack()` and `orderBehind()` which apply only to AIR application windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the AIR sandbox does not use that OS feature. If it is a must have, you can write an ANE native extension, and implement it in WinAPI.